# javascript manipulate json object

Tags: javascript, json

For example, I have the following JSON object `json_obj1`

```
json_obj1 = {x:{id:1,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.4}}}
```

Now, how could I add the following object (using javascript):

```
   y:{id:2,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.4}}
```

to `json_obj1` so that it will be:

```
{x:{id:1,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.4}},y:{id:2,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.4}}}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just set the field **y** of your json_obj1

```
json_obj1 = {x:{id:1,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.4}}}
json_obj1.y = {id:2,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.4}}
```

Now json_obj1 = {x:{id:1,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.4}},y:{id:2,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.4}}}

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear as if your question actually involves JSON. The first code fragment is just a JavaScript object literal. Given your description of the problem, something like this should work:

```
json_obj1 = {x:{id:1,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.4}}};
json_obj1.y = {id:2,bars:{show:true,barWidth:0.4}};
```

This will give you the desired contents in json_obj1;